# How do I expose Actuator endpoints in Swagger UI?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, spring-boot-actuator

How do I expose Actuator endpoints in Swagger UI? I hoped I could just flip the `show-actuator` flag

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    enabled: true
    path: /swagger-ui
    config-url: /swagger-ui/config
  show-actuator: true
```

but doing so creates a circular dependency on start-up (everything works great without the flag)

```
ERROR 10972 --- [dynamic-gateway] [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.ServerHttpSecurityConfiguration
┌─────┐
|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration$EnableWebFluxConfiguration
↑     ↓
|  swaggerWebFluxConfigurer defined in class path resource [org/springdoc/webflux/ui/SwaggerConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  actuatorProvider defined in class path resource [org/springdoc/webflux/core/configuration/SpringDocWebFluxConfiguration$SpringDocWebFluxActuatorConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  webEndpointReactiveHandlerMapping defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/reactive/WebFluxEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  gatewayControllerEndpoint defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gateway/config/GatewayAutoConfiguration$GatewayActuatorConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  modifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gateway/config/GatewayAutoConfiguration.class]
└─────┘
```

My related dependencies:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<!-- ... -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

the error message states a circular dependency with spring cloud gateway and spring security. I build a small app that is using webflux with springdoc and actuator and it works just fine.

I assume there is some other configuration that is interfering on your side.
Maybe you can give more information about your security and gateway config.